# Revert changes made using pm grant on ADB

Tags: android, permissions, adb, sql-grant

I'm with a bit of a problem.

I installed an apk on my LG G5 that customizes the navigation bar for Android 7.0+ devices. [Custom Navigation Bar](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-custom-navigation-bar-customize-t3590967)

For it to work on unrooted devices, you have to use adb to permit the app to write secure settings on android.

Using ADB I wrote the following command:

pm grant xzy.paphonb.systemuituner android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS

Afterwards, the app tested my phone to see if it was compatible. If the navbar buttons disappeared, my phone was not compatible. Well, that's what happened, and now I lost the navbar buttons.

I restarted the phone, uninstalled the app and nothing, I cannot get the buttons back.

What should I do? How do I revert changes made by an app to the Android navbar?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I used the following line

```
adb shell settings delete secure sysui_nav_bar
```

...and restarted the phone. Problem solved!